# Angular 8 Printing out JSON elements from GET API Call

Tags: angular, api, get

I am working on a project that calls an API and prints out elements of the JSON file from the GET method in Angular. I understand how to call the API (all of the imports are in the right place), and I understand how to get elements from an object if there is only one object, but I am lost on what to do if there is more than one object in the file:
For testing, I set my URL to be https://api.github.com/users

Here is my typescript class with the method I call in the HTML file:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  url = 'https://api.github.com/users';
  response: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  
  }

  ngOnInit(): void{
    
  }

  onCreateData(){
    this.loginPassed = true;

    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((response) => {
      this.response = response;
      console.log(this.response);
    });
  }

}
```

Here is my HTML file:

```
<button
    class="btn btn-primary"
    (click)="onCreateData()">Submit</button>
<p *ngIf="loginPassed">Data from API: {{ response?.login }}</p>
```

How can I print out the login of each user from this API? Currently nothing prints unless I set the URL to be more specific, like https://api.github.com/users/mojombo.

Comment: If you just wanted to print out then use console.log(JSON.Stringify(this.response));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is an array of users, in your html you are still treating it like an object instead.

```html
<p *ngFor="let user of response">
  {{ user.login }}
</p>
```

Comment: How do I keep the *ngIf as well? when I add the *ngFor, I get the error: "Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with * "

Comment: Yes u can not use ngIf and ngFor on on element 

U need ngContainer https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

Answer (score 1):

If u are facing
"Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with * " then use [ng-container](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/)

```
<ng-container *ngIf="loginPassed">
<p *ngFor="let item of this.response"> {{item.login}}</p>
</ng-container>
```